# IE 7 CSS float issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm having issues with my mandatoryIndicator class asterisks and their appearance in IE7.  For some reason the asterisk appears almost on top of the City: label in the form but it looks fine in Firefox and IE 8 and above. I've also included the affected part of the HTML as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
.mandatoryIndicator {
    margin: 0 0 0 -.75em;
    padding: 0 4px 0 2px;
    color: #cc0000;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

<td class="alignTop width35">
   <label for="mailingCityEntry">
      <span class="mandatoryIndicator" title="Mandatory">*</span>
      City:
  </label>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ demo?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `negative value` to `margin` in CSS. This always produces style issue in IE7. Anyway, there you should not use position: relative for inline element (`span`). It is only used for block level elements, `i.e. div`, to contain other elements.